# Display container names along with their uptime on grafana dashboard

Tags: grafana, prometheus, cadvisor, prometheus-node-exporter

I want to display all running containers name with their uptime on grafana Dashbaord. I am using Prometheus, CAdvisor, node_exporter.

Comment: have you able to achieve that? could you please share the docker-compose file if you did